# [Rails][Omniauth] Handling Facebook cancel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook, cancel-button

I use omniauth with facebook log in in my app and I'd like to know where I can change the redirect url when user presses cancel while logging in? So far I've found out that pressing cancel gets my app into new action of SessionController which inherits from DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController but I was unable to find anything in my config filles telling it to do it(except for mount_devise_token_auth_for pointing to my SessionController. I'd like to redirect user to a different address.

Comment: Could you use jQuery to prevent the default click behavior?

Comment: @Eric I don't think so because once you click on "sign in with facebook" button you're redirected to facebook login page and there's the cancel button I'm talking about. I think my scripts aren't available there.